# Best Practice: SQL Scripting or Trusting GORM

Tags: grails

I have always scripted all DB changes. But I'm wondering if I really need to do that with Grails applications, since GORM will make the changes automatically.

So what's the best practice for managing database changes in a Grails application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the pattern that I've used on several large Grails projects (and some smaller ones):

1. *In GORM we trust*™ for the first
   stages of development
   (pre-production / without data)
2. Just before releasing to the
   production environment start using a
   tool like [Autobase](http://www.grails.org/plugin/autobase), [Liquibase](http://www.grails.org/plugin/liquibase), [Database Migration Tasks](http://www.grails.org/plugin/dbmigrate) (similar to RoR's rake), or another schema versioning utility.
3. Maintain all database changes
   through the tool in an automated
   fashion.
4. Test your migrations, by writing tests that exercise corner cases and data integrity to the level that you are comfortable running them on production data.

I wouldn't use straight GORM in production unless it is a smaller project that can handle a few possible speed bumps and manual interventions.

Once you start managing several environments (local development, QA/UAT, Staging, Production) you be glad that you spent the time to manage your DB changes.

Liquibase and Autobase both give you some good tools for writing many of the common refactorings, but you can always drop down into raw SQL if you want/need to.

Answer (score 2):

GORM won't handle all schema changes automatically; for example, if you delete a field from one of your domain objects, GORM won't delete the corresponding database column.

There are a couple of Grails plugins to manage database migration - see [Autobase](http://grails.org/plugin/autobase) and [Liquibase](http://grails.org/plugin/liquibase).  I'd say that using whichever of these meets your needs more closely is the best practice; here's a good [blog post](http://pillartechnology.com/blog/?p=57) that explains a few gotcha's with both plugins.

Comment: Thanks. The fact that GORM doesn't do everything decides it for me.